# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in Joomla

Tags: joomla, max, execution, fatal-error

I created a joomla site on my shared hosting this morning. Everything was going great, I was uploading content. And suddenly when I went to create my third category, I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/mysite/public_html/libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php on line 208

I tried `max_execution` in a custom php.ini but it has still not helped me.

I am unable to contact my hosting company as they do not have a support forum or anything.

Is there any way to repair this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dasun is right, 32 mb is an awful lot of memory:

turn the debug feature on (administrator -> global configuration -> system -> debug system) and you'll see who's eating up so much memory. If you can't get rid of the module/component, try to enable cache with a long timeout.

And definitely change hosting provider as soon as possible!

Comment: I tried to access the joomla global configs but it gave me the same error. Its always pointing at libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php which is ofc, A file programmed by someone at joomla I believe. And I dont think they would give out the package if there is a never ending loop.

Comment: definitely not anything like that, however this library is called by many third-party components and it could be one of them, the debug will give you a basic trace to start from

Answer (score 0):

*Yep get a new host — how they function without a means of contacting them is beyond me.*

The error is saying that you've only got a 32Mb allowance for PHP to run in and when PHP tried to allocate more than that it failed.

You could try increasing the setting for PHP in a site based `php.ini` file. e.g.

```
memory_limit=64M;
```

Or, if a local `php.ini` doesn't work you could try adding in this to the top of your `.htaccess` (assuming you're on a LAMP server)

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

If your host allows it this will override the `memory_limit` setting for just that site.

Comment: Tried that but I cant get the company to restart Apache. I believe I have bugged them too much they stopped responding to my emails.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a customer with a very similar problem.  They have a cPanel site, where the default memory allotment was set as 32M.  I found another forum where they suggested adding the line below to both the index.php in the Joomla home space, and also in the index.php file in the administrator folder.  Worked like a charm.  I added it directly below the opening php tag.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
```

This answer was found at http://www.robertwent.com/blog/joomla/19-joomla-increase-php-local-memory-limit-without-changing-server-settings

Hope it works for you

(this is my first "answer" on this site ... apologies if I've not answered in the the site's official way)